# How to set the value of a FormControl before sending the Form to a server

Tags: angular

Below I have a group of radio buttons that show / hide a textbox.

> If rdo1 is selected, show the textbox.
>
> If rdo2 is selected, hide the textbox.

This is done in my `updateShowTxtOtherCompanyName()` method below.

Here is my issue:

Currently, the user can enter text in the textbox & then select rdo2.
In this scenario, the textbox is hidden as expected. But when the user sends the form now, the value in the textbox will be sent to the server rather than a null value.

My question is - how do I set the value of my textfield to null inside my `updateShowTxtOtherCompanyName()` method? I.e. if the user selects rdo2, then the ***OtherCompanyName*** value should be null

I'm hiding the textbox with this code:

```
<radio-button-wrapper formControlName="damageReported" name="damageReported">
    <radio heading="Yes" value="Yes" data-orientation="inline" cid="damageReportedYes" name="damageReportedYes" (click)="updateShowTxtOtherCompanyName('show')">
    </radio>
    <radio heading="No" value="No" data-orientation="inline" cid="damageReportedNo" name="damageReportedNo"(click)="updateShowTxtOtherCompanyName('hide')">
    </radio>
</radio-button-wrapper>

<div *ngIf="showTxtOtherCompanyName ">
    <input formControlName="otherCompanyName" id="otherCompanyName" type="text" [required]="showSelfRiskAmount === true" />
</div>
```

.ts

```
updateShowTxtOtherCompanyName(show: string): void {
    if (show === 'show') {
        this.showTxtOtherCompanyName = true;
    } else {
        this.showTxtOtherCompanyName = false;
        // TODO: need to set otherCompanyName to null here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable it.

```
<div [show]="showTxtOtherCompanyName ">
    <input formControlName="otherCompanyName" id="otherCompanyName" type="text" [required]="showSelfRiskAmount === true" [disabled]="showTxtOtherCompanyName " />
</div>
```

Disabled fields will not be returned by the `myForm.value` property. If you want them, you will have to use `myForm.getRawValue()`.

[Documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue)

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6rhu5c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: If I use .getRawValue(), will the disabled fields post _null_?

Comment: I added `[disabled]="showTxtOtherCompanyName` as shown above, but it is still working the same as previous. The otherCompanyName is still being posted

Comment: @user9847788 indeed, you have to do it in the TS, forgot that part. [Check it in action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6rhu5c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) !

Answer (score 1):

Use `setValue()` as below -

```
updateShowTxtOtherCompanyName(show: string): void {
    if (show === 'show') {
        this.showTxtOtherCompanyName = true;
    } else {
        this.showTxtOtherCompanyName = false;
        // TODO: need to set otherCompanyName to null here
        this.otherCompanyName.setValue(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is where I'm declaring `otherCompanyName`: `ngOnInit() {
    this.damageDetailsTwoForm = this.fb.group({
      injuryType: new FormControl('Bumps, scratches & damage', Validators.required),
      damageReported: new FormControl('Yes', Validators.required),
      otherCompanyName: new FormControl(),
    });
  }`

Comment: I used your code like so `this.damageDetailsTwoForm.controls['otherCompanyName'].setValue(null);` but it has not solved the issue. It's still posting the value

Comment: Try like this : `this.damageDetailsTwoForm.controls.otherCompanyName.setValue(null);`